# Faye with Rails : no disconnect message on Firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket, faye

I'm working on a rails 4.2 app using gem 'faye', '~> 1.0.3', gem 'faye-rails', '~> 2.0.0' and gem 'faye-redis', '~> 0.2.0', with a Thin server.

Everything works fine on Chrome. 
Everything works fine on Firefox except user disconnection. 
I identify disconnection based on incoming message on '/meta/disconnect/' channel and a home made timeout, but on Firefox disconnect messages are never sent.

**Investigations**

- I have systematically the following message on Firefox before unload : *"The connection to ws:://localhosot:3000/faye was interrupted while the page was loading"*. Could it prevent disconnect message being sent ?
- I noticed that disconnect message is sent and caught on Firefox if websocket is disabled (`faye.disable('websocket')`, client side). This works even as I have a similar error message in Firefox console (*"connection interrupted while the page was loading"*). But I'd be really sad if I had to forbid websocket, and would like to find an other, better solution.
- on Chrome, on each page change I have a POST request to faye followed by a GET request with status 101 (normal behaviour, as far as I know); on Firefox I have the same + another POST (status 200). I don't see much differences between the first 2, except on Switching protocol request, (Firefox `Connection = keep-alive, Upgrade` ; Chrome `Connection = Upgrade`).

I don't manage to understand where does the problem come from, if it's a bug or a problem of configuration, and any help would be welcome. I'll be glad to provide any information that could help.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with Firefox. '/meta/disconnect ' is never received by the server. Very frustrating!

Comment: In faye project issues, Faye's creator answer to this problem can be found  (https://github.com/faye/faye/issues/366). He suggests to use monitoring to catch disconnected event instead of message. Unfortunately, the monitoring API doesn't provide any means to get message data (and so, to identify disconnected user), as far as I know.